# HTML - Load Selenium content after the rest of the page is done loading

Tags: python, html, selenium, flask

A section of my website includes some content that I need to acquire from another website using selenium. But getting that info causes the page to load with 3-4 second delay to account for the web scraping process. I would like to load everything BUT the Selenium  content first, THEN load the section containing the acquired content (maybe even display a flashing "loading" label while that's happening, but that's not strictly necessary.)
Example page:

```
<body>
   <div class="container">
      // This part should load instantly //
      <div>
         <h1>Current Stock Information</h1>
         <p class="lead">Here is the information for the stocks you want (wait until it loads): 
         </p>
      </div>

      // This part should load when Selenium has done its thing //  
      <div>
         // For reference: data is passed in through Flask and for simplicity's sake let's say 
            there's only one company I'm interested in //
         <h4>{{ company_name }}</h4>
         <p>{{ stock_val }}</p>
      </div>

   </div>
</body>
```

Edit: Flask Code

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from selenium import Webriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

app = Flask(__name__)
url = '...'

def get-values(url):
    browser = webdriver.Chrome()
    browser.get(url)
    html = browser.page_source
    souppage = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    elements = souppage.find_all("strong")  # returns list of 2 elements
    mylist = []
    for element in elements:
        mylist.append(element.text)
    return mylist

@app.route('/')
def index():
    values = get-values(url)
    company = values[0]
    stock = values[1]
    return render_template('example.html', company_name=company, 
                           stock_val=stock)
```

Comment: please provide code snippet which you have tried from your end.

Comment: There you go. I think the way I'd accomplish what I'm trying to do is with JS, however I'm still very much a newbie with that.